# How to count by 1 in a setInterval loop?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to set up a discord.js command that counts by 1 every 5 seconds (example: 1, then 5 seconds later it says 2, then 5 seconds later it says 3, etc). but everything I tried doesn't work, can I get help?

This is for a bot I'm coding for a server, I've tried using i++ in the loop but it doesn't work.

```
var interval = setInterval (function () {
    var i = 0;
    i++;
    message.channel.send(i)
}, 7000);
```

I expected it to say 1 and then 5 seconds later it would say 2, but it just keeps saying "1" every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the value of `i` when the loop starts

```
var interval = setInterval (function () {
    var i = 0; <<<<<<<<<<<< right here
    i++;
    message.channel.send(i)
}, 7000);
```

You'll need to change the declaration of that variable to outside the loop. Something like this should work:

```
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval (function () {
    i++;
    message.channel.send(i)
}, 7000);
```